# Plotting range for same variable across two conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an input matrix consists of 5 columns and 12 rows.

[image: Input matrix]

I am trying to plot a range for same variables (lets say width) across two methods/conditions (Paper, estimated). I am able to plot range across one methods/condition using code:

```
Input <- read.table("File.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
ggplot(Input, aes(x=Trait))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype=3,color="Black")+
  geom_point(aes(y=min),size=3,color="darkgreen")+
  geom_point(aes(y=max),size=3,color="darkgreen")+ labs(y="-log10(P)", x="Traits") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: For Paper Method]
[image: For estimated Method]

But I want to plot each variable across methods together in the same plot. I can do this by adding an extra suffix with each variable [image: combine image] Is there a nicer way to do this? I have tried shape=Method but it's not working for me, Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest mapping `Method` on `color` instead of `shape`. But hey. It's your plot. (; To achieve your desired result without adding a suffix you could make use of `position_dodge` like so:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Input, aes(x = Trait, shape = Method)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, group = Method), linetype = 3, color = "Black", position = position_dodge(.6)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = min), color = "darkgreen", size = 3, position = position_dodge(.6)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = max), color = "darkgreen", size = 3, position = position_dodge(.6)) +
  labs(y = "-log10(P)", x = "Traits") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(42)

Input <- tibble(
  Method = rep(c("Paper", "Estimated"), each = 3),
  Trait = rep(c("Width", "Density", "Lenght"), 2),
  Count = rep(c(2, 4, 10), 2),
  min = runif(6, 5, 7),
  max = min + runif(6, 0, 10)
)
```